# The best overload method for '...' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I created a player class and I am trying to use my player class with my menu driven player program but I keep getting the error The best overload method for 'Assignment_7.Program.ProcessCreate(int, string, string, int, int, Assignment_7.Player, ref in, int)' has some invalid arguments with my methods I am trying to use with my menu

Any help would be appreciated.

//The MAXPLAYERS constant is the physical table size
        const Int32 MAXPLAYERS = 23;

```
    //Declare the player tables

    Player[] players = new Player[MAXPLAYERS];

    //Keep track of the actual number of players (i.e. logical table size)
    Int32 playerCount = 0;

    //Main Driver
    char menuItem;
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the player system...\n");
    menuItem = GetMenuItem();
    while (menuItem != 'X')
    {
        ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
//new Player(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists)
//Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
static char GetMenuItem()
{
    char menuItem;
    DisplayMenu();
    menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    while (menuItem != 'C'
        && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
    return menuItem;
}

static void DisplayMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease pick an item:");
    Console.WriteLine("C - Create Player");
    Console.WriteLine("R - Retrive Player");
    Console.WriteLine("U - Update Player");
    Console.WriteLine("D - Delete Player");
    Console.WriteLine("L - List Players");
    Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
}

//Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
    Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
{
    switch (menuItem)
    {
        case 'C':
            ProcessCreate(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, ref playerCount, players, MAXPLAYERS);
            break;
        case 'L':
            ProcessList(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists,players, ref playerCount);
            break;
        case 'R':
            ProcessRetrive(number, lastName, firstName, goals,  assists, ref playerCount MAXPLAYERS);
            break;

        case 'U':
            ProcessUpdate(number, firstName,lastName,goals ,assists, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
            break;
        case 'D':
            DeletePlayer(number, firstName,lastName,goals ,assists, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
               break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You're giving ProcessCreate an array of Players. It's not expecting that from what I can see unless you have another method overload that accepts an array. Also it expects a Player when you give it playerCount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the last parameter (`MAXPLAYERS`) in the call to `ProcessMenuItem`

```
ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS)
```

Some other suggestions:

- Make `ProcessMenuItem` return an `int` rather then using a `ref` parameter
- If `MAXPLAYERS` is a `const` member then it doesn't need to be a parameter for `ProcessMenuItem` (as it stands now it's hiding the `const` member).
- Consider creating a `Player` class and passing that to `ProcessMenuItem` rather than several parameters.